# Would a parent leaving their child at safe haven to avoid paying child support be guilty of a crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, children, kidnapping

Let me start by saying this is a purely hypothetical question asked only out of curiosity, I have no unwanted children nor am I horrible enough person to do this if I did.

Still lets say hypothetically that two teenagers end up having an unplanned child.  The mother wants to keep and raise the child, but the father does not want to be a parent to the child, and also does not want to be forced to pay child support for the child if the mother raises it.

At some point the father offers to take the newborn child for an evening from the mother to watch the child, which the mother agrees to.  However, instead of caring for the child as promised he instead takes it to a safe haven location and drops it off to be adopted; despite knowing the mother wanted to raise the child.

The man is not guilty of kidnapping, as I understand it, as the biological father has the right to travel with the child.  But surely he is guilty of some sort of crime for doing this?  Can he be compelled to reveal which haven he left the child so that the mother can find it before it's put up for adoption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Child Abduction

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) Crimes Act 1900 [s87](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s87.html)

> 87 CHILD ABDUCTION
>
> (1) A person who takes or detains a child with the intention of removing or keeping the child from the lawful control of any person having parental responsibility for the child, without the consent of that person, is liable to imprisonment for 10 years.

Comment: and in the U.S.?